# Kivy text refresh

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, kivy-recycleview

I have the main file main.py and several other design files for different screens. On the Home screen, the text should change relative to the value in money. But it does not change and I do not understand why

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.size = (430, 930)

class ShopScreen(Screen):
    Builder.load_file("Shop.kv")

class ItemsScreen(Screen):
    Builder.load_file("Items.kv")

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    Builder.load_file("Home.kv")
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.money = 224
        self.ids.coins.text = str(self.money)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_text, self.money)

    def update_text(self, dt):
        self.money += 1
        self.ids.coins.text = str(self.money)

class WindowManager(FloatLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(ShopScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(ItemsScreen(name='items'))
        sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='main'))
        return WindowManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LabelBase.register(name="Press Start 2P",
                    fn_regular='./font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf')
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
#: import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<WindowManager>:
    MDBottomNavigation: 
        font_name: "./font/PressStart2P-Regular.ttf"
        panel_color: get_color_from_hex("#1B1B1B")
        text_color_active: 1, 1, 0, 1
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            icon: 'home'
            name: 'shop'
            text: 'МАГАЗИН'
            ShopScreen:
 
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            icon: 'home'
            name: 'main'
            text: 'ГОЛОВНА' 
            HomeScreen:
  
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            icon: 'home'
            name: 'items'
            text: 'ХЕЛПЕРИ'
            ItemsScreen:
```

home.kv

```
<HomeScreen@Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 10
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            padding: 40
            MDLabel:
                font_name: "Press Start 2P"
                text: 'name'
            MDLabel:
                id: coins
                font_name: "Press Start 2P"
                text: '0'
                halign: 'right'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 20
            Image:
                size_hint: 1, 0.9
                source: "boss.png"
            Button:
                font_name: "Press Start 2P"
                text: 'Грати'
                background_color: 0,0,0,0
                size_hint: .9, 0.1
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba: (27/255,27/255,27/255,1)
                    RoundedRectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                        radius: [30]

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: 1, 0.4
            padding: 40
            spacing: 40 
            Label: 
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.15, 'center_y': 0.1}
                size_hint: 1, 0.1
                text: 'артефакти'
                font_name: "Press Start 2P"
            BoxLayout:
                spacing: 40 
                size_hint: 1, 1

                MainItem1:

                MainItem2:

                MainItem3:
```

How to display the data from the variable money in the text and also to update it (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

In your `HomeScreen` class, you're scheduling the `update_text` method with a delay of `self.money`, which is initially set to 224. This means the `update_text` method will be called every 224 seconds, not every second.

To update the text every second, you should schedule it with an interval of 1 second (or whatever interval you prefer) and not with `self.money`.

Updated HomeScreen class:

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    Builder.load_file("Home.kv")
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.money = 224
        self.ids.coins.text = str(self.money)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_text, 1)  # Update every second

    def update_text(self, dt):
        self.money += 1
        self.ids.coins.text = str(self.money)
```

This will update the text every second with the updated value of `self.money`.

Make sure to remove the `self.money` parameter from `Clock.schedule_interval`.

Comment: I got it, I did it. But it still displays 0. See my repository for the full code

https://github.com/AsterPy/glmglm